# I'm getting an error from the implementation of my region of interest

Tags: c++, opencv

Error message:

> (-215) 0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols &&
>   0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows in
>   function cv::Mat::Mat

This is my code

```
Rect eye_rec(200, 300, 168, 168);
Point hand_pos(100, 100);
Mat des, mask = (cv::Mat::zeros(hand.size(), CV_8UC1));
mask(eye_rec).setTo(255);
seamlessClone(eye,hand, mask,hand_pos,des,NORMAL_CLONE);
imshow("clone", des);
waitKey(0);
```

i cant really understand the error message though..

Comment: @FilipKočica the size is 490 x 612 while eye is 168 x168

Comment: I also found [quite good tutorial on Seamless cloning](https://www.learnopencv.com/seamless-cloning-using-opencv-python-cpp/). You might take a look :-)

Comment: @FilipKočica thanks a lot that will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error code generally means, that ROI you want to crop is out of the bounds of the source matrix - e.g. source matrix is of size 480x480 and you want to crop out ROI of size 300x300 from position (200, 200), where 300+200 > 480.

---

According to [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/photo/doc/cloning.html)

```
src – Input 8-bit 3-channel image.
dst – Input 8-bit 3-channel image.
mask – Input 8-bit 1 or 3-channel image.
result – Output image with the same size and type as dst.
```

src, dst and result should be of type `CV_8UC3` - three channel images, while you are passing just one channel images `CV_8UC1`, which most likely cause the error here.

The solution is to use 3-channel (color) images or different operation accepting 1-channel images.

Comment: have changed the image type, and the ROI value but still getting the same error, kindly give me a recommendation and the reason why?... thanks alot

Comment: Can you provide how `eye` and `hand` are loaded ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    hand.convertTo(hand, CV_8UC3);
    eye.convertTo(eye, CV_8UC3);
    Point hand_pos(hand.cols/2,hand.rows/2); //this code should put the eye image in the middle of the hand image
    Mat des, mask = (cv::Mat::zeros(eye.size(), CV_8UC3)); 
    des.convertTo(des, CV_8UC3);

    mask = 255 * Mat::ones(eye.rows, eye.cols, eye.depth()); // creating a mask of all white from the eye image
    seamlessClone(eye,hand, mask,hand_pos,des,NORMAL_CLONE);
   imshow("normalclone", des); waitKey(0);
    seamlessClone(eye,hand,mask,hand_pos,des, MIXED_CLONE);
   imshow("mixclone",des); waitKey(0)
    waitKey(0);
```

This change helped me, hope it helps others too, thanks @Filip Kočica